# error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/orientation' with config '' .aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, androidx

I've got this compile error!
I checked similar problems on stackoverflow but all of them were about different errors & not  " attr/orientation' with config '' ", but they didn't work for my problem! 
I'm using androidx library , kotlin ,Gradle 4.10.1 ,

I do these steps, but still no result:

1- Clean Project

2- Rebuild

3- Invalidate caches / Restart

4- made another attrs.xml file on the folder : res->values-v21

5-so many other ways...

but all of them just failed!
Any solution?

Comment: which other libraries do you use?

Comment: I mentioned below, Thanks @RobinVinzenz it was because of conflicts between libraries

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I find the problem, it is a bug and I reported it to Google ( b.android.com ) & they answered

> Yep, we are aware of this issue, it will be fixed in the next alpha release.
>   this is the : [issue link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121395935)

.

So how to solve it:
   I faced the problem when updated to alpha3 version of library in build.gradle (Module) :

```
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

Just downgrade it to lower version:

```
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

and now it's ok.

The problem was the conflict between  constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3 library and attrs.xml  merging on compile time!

and for you it might be just conflicts between some other libraries ( just check last updated libraries )

Comment: True. You can raise the issue as google bug, it seems to happen to a lot of users

Comment: Tnx @RJFares,  I reported it as a bug on b.android.com , and they answered: We're aware of this bug & will be OK on the  next alpha version

Comment: I was so confused by this error and you saved my ass and hair. Merry Christmas btw.

Comment: @jackz314 this bug waste almost one day of mine! Merry Christmass :)

Comment: helped me too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978229/android-resource-compilation-failed-error-duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-o

Comment: In case you created a custom "Orientation" styleable attribute in attrs.xml, just rename it to e. g. "CustomOrientation". Don't forget to update your code and XMLs where the attribute is used. After cleaning the project the build finished successfully. In case of a clash with a 3rd party library downgrading to 2.0.0-alpha2 is probably the only option.

Comment: Ah! Version conflict always would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It happens if you are you have migrate to Androidx and you add android.support library. Just try to find Androidx library for the android.support library you are using. 
 For example.
  Change

> implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

To

> implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'