# AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/orientation' with config ''

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, grid-layout, aapt

I am using a third party library ( cosmos calendar) and it have android.support dependency while i am using androidx for all my project .this caused a conflict, and this error on the gridLayout dependecy :

```
AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/orientation' with config ''.
```

i remove gridlayout or the cosmos calendar dependency ,the project builds but can't build using both dependencies. how can i workaround this conflict ?

Comment: Close and re import your project.

Comment: this doesn't do anything, still the same issue

Comment: Can be helpful, Please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895569/error-duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-orientation-with-config-aapt-v2-a/53895653#53895653

Answer (score 0):

I ended up importing the whole cosmoCalendar library from github'since it is an open source project) migrating and refactoring it to work with AndroidX then packed it in a .aar file and add it as dependency in my project , everything then worked fine .